# Active class is removed after page loads in navigation bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code but not working...  It will remove active class after page refresh.

html code

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="about-us.php">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#navbar ul li a').click(function(){
                $('li a').removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: what you want excatly? Please Explaing and Share your Html code also

Comment: You will have to do something with `URL` on `page-load`

Comment: kindly explain your purpose

Comment: Actually I have only one file header.php that I have included in all the files when I click on Navigation menu that <li> should be active ...

Comment: You need to apply the active class for li tag and not for a tag.Instead of $(this).addClass() try $(this).parent().addClass("currunt")

Comment: As I understand,you want one link to be default active when page loads but that is not happening

Comment: But that active class will remove after page refresh

Comment: you need to add "currunt" class manually in one of the links which you want to show active on page refesh. like <li class='currunt'><a href="about-us.php">About us</a>
    </li> Please let me know, if i m going in right direction

Comment: as @DeepakGarg said, you need to add class in html first. But I think you would need to add class to `a` tag as you are adding `currunt` class to `a` tag in your script. And if possible, think about making it `current` ;)

Comment: *"class will remove after page refresh"* - yes, because you've refreshed the page.  Every time the page "refreshes" or "loads" you get all new html and all new javascript.  All the classes are back to their defaults and all the javascript variables are reset.  You can't store js and/or classes over a page "refresh".

Answer (score 4):

I create an example using localStorage to set the active element and to keep it active on page load:

```
$('#navbar ul li a').click(function() {
  $('li a').removeClass("currunt");
  $(this).addClass("currunt");
  localStorage.setItem('active', $(this).parent().index());
});

var ele = localStorage.getItem('active');
$('#navbar ul li:eq(' + ele + ')').find('a').addClass('currunt');
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aojtoyye/)

Comment: This will work but It not removes 'active' class after added to any class... when I visit another page again and come to that page 'active' class is already added to previous one

Comment: `active` class you refer to `currunt` class right? Also users redirect using only this menu right? Because as you see I create a demo that requires the user click on an anchor to work.

Answer (score 0):

For your current setup, it seems you do not need to use javascript to add classes as these are direct links with no dropdowns, so obviously clicking them will redirect to another page and classes will be removed. A simple solution without JS is like this:

1. Add classes to your links
2. Change your css accordingly to highlight current page's link

Your css would be like this:

```
.about-body .about-link,
.portfolio-body .portfolio-link,
.services-body .services-link,
.contact-body .contact-link,
.blog-body .blog-link
{
    background-color: red; /* or other styles you have in your active class */
}

<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="about-link"><a href="about-us.php">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="portfolio-link"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="services-link"><a href="services.php">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-link"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="blog-link"><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

One thing to note here is that you would need to have the body classes accordingly on every page. e.g. your about-us page should have `about-body` class on `body` tag. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: my html is not appearing as code for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if the jquery is loaded in the page?
try adding a `console.log("item clicked")` in the click function to see if its running

the same code works for me, i just added this css

```
.current {
  background-color: white;
  font:black;
  font-size:19px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/0w0rnx4x/